# This function is injective

Tags: functions

I'm trying to prove this function is injective:

$$f:P(\mathbb N)\to \mathbb R, f(M)=\sum_{n\in M}3^{-n}$$

I've already proved that this function is well-defined but I couldn't prove this function is injective. Even to the case $|M|=2$, I found difficult, I think I didn't catch the essense of what means this function be injective.

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "proving that the function is well-defined". The function is given by a concrete recipe on each $M$, so there is nothing to check regarding its definition.

Comment: It's injective because the base-$3$ expansion of a real number is unique (unique enough for our purposes, anyway). I would have made this an answer, but now I think of it I've never seen a proof of that...

Comment: @MartinArgerami That's not true, strictly speaking. The sum could diverge, or the sum's value could depend on the summation order.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I agree with you

Comment: @fgp: good point.

Comment: @JackM: you could start proving it for base 10 instead of base 3 :D

Comment: @fgp Why the sum's value doesn't depend on the summation order when $M$ is infinity?

Comment: @user42912 Because all the summands are positive, and thus if the sum converges at all (which it does), it converges absolutely. That suffices to guarantee that the order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be distinct subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. We need to show that $f(M_1)\ne f(M_2)$.

Let $m$ be the smallest integer which is in one of $M_1$ or $M_2$, but not in the other. We may assume that $m\in M_1$.

Note that 
$$f(M_1)-f(M_2)\ge \frac{1}{3^m} -\sum_{m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^i}.$$
 By the formula for the sum of a geometric series, $\sum_{m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{i}}=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^m}$, so $f(M_1)-f(M_2)$ is positive.

**Remark:** There is less to this than meets the eye. Our sums are the base $3$ expansions of certain reals, and base $3$ expansions that avoid the "trit" $2$ are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Injective means that different choice of $M$ will always produce different numbers. 
Suppose that 
$$
\sum_{n\in M}3^{-n}=\sum_{n\in N}3^{-n}.
$$
Let $k=\min\{n:\ n\in M\setminus N\ \text{ or }n\in N\setminus M\}$. This means that $\{1,\ldots,k-1\}\subset M\cap N$. Thus the all the terms with $n<k$ of the sums are equal. So
$$
\sum_{n\in M,\ n\geq k}3^{-n}=\sum_{n\in N,\ n\geq k}3^{-n}.
$$

Assume that $k\in M$ and $k\not\in N$ (otherwise we exchange roles). Then
$$
3^{-k}+\sum_{n\in M,\ n\geq k+1}3^{-n}=\sum_{n\in N,\ n\geq k+1}3^{-n}.
$$
That is 
$$
3^{-k}=\sum_{n\in N,\ n\geq k+1}3^{-n}-\sum_{n\in M,\ n\geq k+1}3^{-n}
\leq\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty3^{-n}=\frac{3^{-k-1}}{1-1/3}=\frac{3^{-k}}2.
$$
We got to a contradiction, that shows that our $k$ cannot exist. So $M=N$.